# An sql query with join involved using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

[image]

[image]

-- 12. (trouble) List all customers, title, artist, quantity ordered

```
SELECT customer_name, title, artist, order_qty 
FROM customers,items,orderline, orders
WHERE  orders.order_id = orderline.order_id
  AND customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id;
```

I tried the query however wont get the results i need, will anyone please take a look.

results below

```
'Cora Blanca', 'Under the Sun', 'Donald Arley', '3'

'Cora Blanca', 'Dark Lady', 'Keith Morris', '3'

'Cora Blanca', 'Happy Days', 'Andrea Reid', '3'

'Cora Blanca', 'Top of the Mountain', 'Janice Jones', '3'

'Cora Blanca', 'Streets from Old', 'Sharon Brune', '3'

'Cora Blanca', 'The Hunt', 'Walter  Alford', '3'

'Cora Blanca', 'Rainbow Row', 'Judy Ford', '3'

'Cora Blanca', 'Skies Above', 'Alexander Wilson', '3'

'Cora Blanca', 'The Seas and Moon', 'Susan Beeler', '3'

'Cora Blanca', 'Greek Isles', 'Benjamin Caudle', '3'
```

Comment: Please take a look at the help centre articles on how to ask a good question. You need to include a clear explanation of the result you need, and what the problem is with what you have now. Please also tag with the type of database you are using (e.gMySQL? Postgres?) and try to apply some basic formatting to make it easier to read.  You could also try creating a live demo on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Although the query here is different, the technique you need to understand is the same. While people here may be happy to help you understand the concepts you are struggling with, simply posting a series of very specific questions which appear to be part of a homework exercise is not a good use of this site, and will ultimately not help you learn.

Comment: Both questions are about how to write an SQL join. You may be changing which tables you are joining and which fields you are selecting, but the _idea_ is the same.  This feels like a homework question, and while it is perfectly fine to ask about how joins works, it is not ok to ask StackOverflow to solve this for you every time you need to write a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the cartesian join that you did because it seems to be improper syntax for what you're trying to do. Specifically, you did not specify appropriate `JOIN` criteria for each of the tables you're trying to `JOIN`. You need to explicitly state their relationships.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    c.customer_name
    ,i.title
    ,i.artist
    ,ol.order_qty
FROM
    Customers AS c
JOIN
    Orders AS o
        ON o.Customer_Id = c.Customer_Id
JOIN
    OrderLine AS ol
        ON ol.Order_Id = o.Order_Id
JOIN
    Items AS i
        ON i.Item_Id = ol.Item_id
```

Rather than using a cartesian join with a `WHERE` clause filter you should use an explicit condition in the `ON` clause to define your `JOIN` criteria. Specially you'll notice that this solution had a condition on the `items` and `orderline` table, where your original query did not.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because you haven't actually explained the changes you've made to the query, and which are important (hint: two of those joins are functionally identical to the original query).

Comment: i didn't down vote down but the query, doesn't seem to work. it has error on o.[customer_id" line

Comment: @Purple_Rain that refers to the `customer_id` column in the `orders` table... Your linked image implies it should exist. Check for typos.

Comment: no the query is now pointing an error c.[customer_name]/// copied and pasted t

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with using , to join tables and qualifying with WHERE clauses, and this was the only form available in early versions of SQL. The JOIN form is certainly more readable, but the only actual problem was the missing condition joining order_lines to items.

Comment: @Purple_Rain I fixed a typo for you. DO you understand what this query accomplishes (typos aside?)

Comment: @IMSoP It's "wrong" because it violates the current ANSI SQL standard. I added the additional conditions **and** moved it to a corrected syntax.

Comment: As for the syntax error, the square bracket syntax for quoting column names only works on MS SQL Server and maybe Oracle; MySQL uses backticks, and Postgres uses double quotes (which are the official standard). In this case, though, there's no reason to quote the names at all.

Comment: hmmm not sure it give me the same thing.. Yes a where clause condition is not used rather join... on specified condition in this one you posted... This is Mysql btw

Comment: @IMSoP I removed the brackets. I didn't notice the "MySQL" in the title... my mistake

Comment: I'm pretty sure both forms of join syntax are in the standard. I agree JOIN + ON is better, but both will work just fine if you get the rest of the query right. The square brackets, however, definitely aren't in the standard, and will only work on a handful of database systems.

Comment: @IMSoP I disagree that both are standard. OP wants an explicit inner join, not an implicit cross join with a where clause.

Comment: Even so, you still think your downvote is justified?

Comment: Thanks this is SQL query i had using before. Got the same result think my foreign keys are wrong... Thanks i understand

Comment: @IMSoP ... for the record. I looked into the standard. The implicit inner join which the OP has used was deprecated in the SQL-92... It will still work in MySQL but it *should not be used*

Comment: A restricted cartesian join is entirely equivalent to an inner join, and there is nothing about it that is non-standard. (There is actually a standard difference in binding precedence between comma-separated lists of tables and JOIN statements) And yes, I still think this answer did a poor job of explaining to someone new to SQL what was wrong with their original attempt.

Comment: The Postgres manual, which mentions the standard frequently, even when it disagrees with it, says INNER and CROSS JOIN "are just a notational convenience, since they do nothing you couldn't do with plain FROM and WHERE." http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM

Comment: @IMSoP The documentation you linked explicitly states that "If multiple sources are specified, the result is the Cartesian product (cross join) of all the sources. But usually qualification conditions are added (via WHERE) to restrict the returned rows to a small subset of the Cartesian product." ... While the end result may be the same **it is incorrect** to say that an explicit inner join is the same as a subset of a cartesian product. When you scale the query in the two methods be explicit with your intent. It's possible that the query plans will not be the same even though the results are.

Comment: I think we could go back and forth forever picking each other up on details. I definitely agree that using comma joins should be discouraged, and makes the OP's mistake less obvious. I disagree that they're in any way against the standard, or that the OP's query couldn't be corrected without switching syntax first, and then showing the equivalent in the better syntax.